# How can I download a binary variant though the Content Delivery web service?

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, odata

The use case is the need for the (plain text) contents of a binary variant in the Tridion Content Delivery web service. The Binary Variant URL is 
`http://localhost:82/odata.svc/BinaryVariants(BinaryId=159,PublicationId=4,VariantId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')`

Experimenting with the CD web service I tried 
`http://localhost:82/odata.svc/BinaryVariants(BinaryId=159,PublicationId=4,VariantId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')/Binary`, This does not work out, the Binary item is the “parent” of the BinaryVariant, it does not contain any binary data.

The BinaryVariant URL gives met the metadata about the Binary such as Path (`/system/config/search.json`) and Type (`application/json`), but not the actual binary contents itself.

Comment: What version of Tridion?

Comment: IIRC, in 2011sp1 you couldn't get binaries via the WS, only their URL on the file system. In 2013 a new feature was introduced where you can do this. But the entity is BinaryContent, not Binary.

Comment: It's on SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Comment: That's the right answer Nick! I checked, there is a BinaryContents collection which contains the binary I am looking for. I did not find it cause there is no relation/link from Binaries or BinaryVariants to this BinaryContents collection.  There is a link from the BinaryContents to BinaryVariants though, strange...

Comment: Ok. Converting to answer so you can give me points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, in 2011sp1 you couldn't get binaries via the WS, only their URL on the file system. In 2013 a new feature was introduced where you can do this. But the entity is BinaryContent, not Binary.

Comment: Yep, This worked for me, just grab the $value from the BinaryContents collction: `http://localhost:82/odata.svc/BinaryContents(BinaryId=159,PublicationId=4,VariantId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')/$value`     There is no relation between the BinaryVariant and the BinaryContents though, so you manually have to construct the BinaryContents URL, as you can see it is similar to the BinaryVariants URL.